# Is IDOR (Insecure Direct Object Reference) a server-side or client-side vulnerability?

Tags: web-application, vulnerability

I want to know if IDOR is a client-side or server-side vulnerability. In my opinion, it is a server-side vulnerability.

Comment: Why do you think it is server-side?

Comment: Have you done any research on this? OWASP has a lot to say: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References

Comment: IDOR is a sever side vulnerability. It is not a matter of opinion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks research effort.

Answer (score 2):

A simple explanation:

> IDOR occurs when a web application improperly or forgets entirely to verify user input, when they are using that as a reference.

It's a sever side verification mechanism that is vulnerable.

> An example is worth a thousands words, so let's say we have a web developer (we will call him Joe) and an attacker (Billy)
>
> Silly Joe, writes a page to edit your profile, you can edit your e-mail, password, name. Sounds fun right?
>   But under the hood, there is a hidden input called "username", the value of which is your username.
>
> It doesn't cross Joe's mind that this could be changed on-the-fly with a plugin such as HTTP Live Headers to anybody's username against its intended use.
>   And so, the username parameter is directly inserted into the prepared MySQL query.
>
> Attacker Billy comes along scouring for weaknesses in the web application, and finds this hidden input.
>   He edits the e-mail field to his secondary e-mail, submits the request, edits it on the fly and changes the username parameter to his friends username.
>
> Luckily for Billy, the request is successful and the query was applied to his friends account, he can now simply send a forgot password reset and steal his account.

REF: http://insecurity.shoutwiki.com/wiki/Insecure_Direct_Object_Reference_(IDOR)

Comment: **tl;dr:** It's a server-sided vulnerability.